# Using cfx_http5 tag to replace cfhttp code

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I am trying to convert the paypal response of the following code

```
<CFHTTP URL="#serverURL#" METHOD="POST" proxyserver=#proxyName# proxyport="#proxyPort#">
              <cfloop collection=#requestData# item="key">
                  <CFHTTPPARAM NAME="#key#" VALUE="#requestData[key]#" TYPE="FormField" ENCODED="YES">
              </cfloop>
            </CFHTTP>
```

usingcfx_htt5 but somehow my try is going wrong:

I gave the following shot, but not working

```
<CFSET BODY="#key#=#requestData[key]#">
<CFX_HTTP5 METHOD="POST" URL="#serverURL#" BODY="#BODY#" OUT="RES">
```

at the top it is using **loop** and proxy and i am not sure how do i do it here

Comment: Phrases like "not working" do not tell us much.  What is the actual result of the code? What result did you expect instead?

Comment: Looking at `http://adiabata.com/cfx_http5.cfm` for the source of that `cfx` tag. Looks like it's only tested through CF 9 and based on C++. I wouldn't trust that it has been updated to handle the latest SSL and other security concerns. If it can't handle `TLS 1.2`, then it won't be able to connect to most sites for much longer. Very soon, my company will not be accepting logins or other communications from connections that do not support TLS 1.2.

Answer (score 3):

I prefer to add all of the FORM parameters to an array and then convert it to a list. Read the documentation and ensure that the values are URLEncoded.  You may need to add additional headers too using. (I prefer to always use a custom user agent.)  If you set SSL="5", you can additionally force the use of the TLS1.2 protocol.

```
<CFSET CRLF=Chr(13) & Chr(10)>
<CFSET Params = ArrayNew(1)>
<CFLOOP COLLECTION=#requestData# ITEM="key">
    <CFSET ArrayAppend(Params, "#key#=#URLEncodedFormat(requestData[key])#">
</CFLOOP>
<CFSET BODY=ArrayToList(Params, "&")>
<CFSET HEADERS="Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded#CRLF#">
<CFX_HTTP5 METHOD="POST" URL="#serverURL#" BODY="#BODY#" HEADERS="#Headers#" OUT="RES" SSL="5">
```